# How to reference/write the file path in Elements.xml for UserControl in Sandbox Solution?

Tags: sandbox-solution, user-controls, assembly-references, elements-xml, module

I have 1 solution (which is deploying as SandBox Solution).

I have added JavaScript files, Images, Application Page & UserControl in one Module under project folder.

I have one Element.xml file which has CustomAction button for Ribbon. Now in this I want to to add UserControl in this.
So I have written,

"Control Id="ControlPageHeader" Sequence="400" ControlSrc="~/MyModuleName/MyTestFolder/MyUserControl.ascx"

And In UserControl, I have added the following line for my JavaScript file reference.
"SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Name="/MyModule/JS/MyJScript.js">

When I create the package & Upload the solution on my site, Button is displayed in the Site, but when I click on the button, it does not take/do any action.

(Image is not displaying on the button also).

I don't know what is the problem ? Either the reference or path ?

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

try the following in your ascx:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Name="MyJScript.js">
```

sharepoint i think if memory servers me right will be looking in the 12hive folder of layouts under templates. If you want a folder than add it within the layouts folder

Templates/Layouts/MyModule/JS/MyJScript.js

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Name="/MyModule/JS/MyJScript.js">
```

somthing similar as to what iv said that you could reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068663/how-to-call-an-external-javascript-file-from-a-webpart